# VSCode Clang C Libraries Importing

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang

Im trying trying to include libraries in vscode, but I currently don't know how to
(Yes I am new to C)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: What libraries in particular? The only library used in that code is the C standard library and that is automatically included and linked. If there is a specific error you are getting then please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69067824/edit) the question to update with the exact error. Also, please note that Stack Overflow is not a replacement for basic research. People are expected to read manuals, search for existing info, read examples, etc and only post a new question if there is still a problem after that.

Comment: I have searched google for 2 hours, and im talking about c windows libraries, like stdio.h, and assert.h

Comment: Those are included by default if your system is set up correctly. Please describe what you have done to set up your system and what specific error you have.

Comment: Im trying to include them, I get this error "main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found"

Comment: It seems, that you have no compiler installed: [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code - Install a compiler](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler)

Comment: I have clang, heres the output

Starting build...
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -g C:\Users\nope\OneDrive\Desktop\Game\main.c -o C:\Users\nope\OneDrive\Desktop\Game\Debug\Launch.exe
clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
C:\Users\nope\OneDrive\Desktop\Game\main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdhio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Im trying trying to include libraries in vscode, but I currently don't know how to

Including standard library functionality in C is usually a simple matter of `#include`ing the right headers (`.h` files). It is exactly so with `stdio.h`.

However, headers do not usually *implement* the functions (like `printf()`, etc), they merely provide an *interface* to the implementation, by means of function prototypes like `int printf(const char *, ...)`, macro definitions like `EOF`, datatypes like `FILE`, etc.

To *actually compile & use*  the functionality of , say, `stdio.h`, you will need your OS to provide a C library implementation. Some operating systems, like GNU/Linux and most BSDs, have this built-in, but commercial systems like Microsoft Windows and Apple's macOS do not, and instead offer easily downloadable/installable toolchains that provide this.

For windows, this would mean installing [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), available free with a [Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/?tab=individual). You needn't install the full fat IDE, at the very least the [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) package will allow you to compile C/C++ projects from the Developer Command Prompt (or use the C library implementation in other compilers like Clang) and more.

On a subjective note, I wouldn't really recommend Clang or MinGW (GCC's Windows version) for compiling on/for Windows, use Microsoft's compiler if possible.